# Solving a Polynomial Expression

Tags: polynomials

If $x$ and $y$ are integral solutions of $$2x^2 -3xy - 2y^2= 7$$
What will be the value of $|x+y|$
I have no idea how to proceed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

$$7=2x^2-3xy-2y^2=x(\underbrace{2x+y})-2y(\underbrace{2x+y})=(2x+y)(x-2y)$$

As $x,y$ are integers so will be $2x+y,x-2y$

What are the [aliquot divisor](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AliquotDivisor.html)s of $7?$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, Thanks for your observation.